# Is it possible to extend Visual Studio Linq-to-Sql designer to support geometry types?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010, geospatial

According to [this blog post](http://destructothedevilcat.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/data-type-not-supported-by-the-designer/), Microsoft will not fix this problem soon. There is the technical possibility to do it ourselves, or we will have to wait for Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Comment: Have you thought about using the VARBINARY(MAX) field? At least you could retrieve the data back from the DB .... I've not tried it but I thought i read that, that could be done....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you made the designer support it the runtime won't.

Comment: And there is any way to extend the runtime?